# Traveling salesman with random initial solution, optimization algorithm returning unexpected result

Tags: kotlin, traveling-salesman

I know traveling salesman is well known, but I need some help on why my optimization algorithm is returning an unexpected result. I have created an initial solution by selecting cities in a random order. I have also created a class with a constructor with the distance matrix and initial solution as parameters. The optimization algorithm is very simple; it swaps two cities and checks if the route distance has been improved, and if it has improved the best solution should be updated. This goes on for 6 iterations. The problem is that the it seems like the best solution is updated and overwritten even if the condition for overwriting it is not met. I will add an image showing the results from a test run.

[image]

It seems like the variable `bestSolution` is overwritten but not `bestDistance`. I must have some sort of tunnel vision, because I can't figure this one out even if the code is really simple. Can someone please chime in why `bestSolution` is overwritten and returned with unexpected result?

Code example below:

```
package RandomMethod

import GreedyHeuristic
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

                                           /*A  B  C*/
    val distances = arrayOf(/*A*/ intArrayOf(0, 2, 7),
                            /*B*/ intArrayOf(2, 0, 9),
                            /*C*/ intArrayOf(7, 9, 0))

    val initalSolution = findRandomRoute(distances)

    println("Initial solution: $initalSolution")
    println("Total distance: ${findTotalDistance(distances, initalSolution)}\n")

    val optimizedSolution = GreedyHeuristic(distances, initalSolution).optimize()

    println("\nOptimized solution with Greedy Heuristic: $optimizedSolution")
    println("Total distance: ${findTotalDistance(distances, optimizedSolution)}")

}

fun areAllCitiesVisited(isCityVisited: Array<Boolean>): Boolean {

    for (visited in isCityVisited) {
        if (!visited) return false
    }
    return true
}

fun findTotalDistance(distances: Array<IntArray>, orderToBeVisited: MutableList<Int>): Int {

    var totalDistance = 0

    for (i in 0..orderToBeVisited.size - 2) {
        val fromCityIndex = orderToBeVisited.get(i)
        val toCityIndex = orderToBeVisited.get(i + 1)
        totalDistance += distances[fromCityIndex].get(toCityIndex)
    }
    return totalDistance
}

fun findRandomRoute(distances: Array<IntArray>): MutableList<Int> {
    val visitedCities: Array<Boolean> = Array(distances.size, {i -> false})

    // Find starting city index. 0 = A, 1 = B, 2 = C .... N = X
    var currentCity = Random().nextInt(distances.size)
    val orderToBeVisited: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(currentCity)

    visitedCities[currentCity] = true

    while (!areAllCitiesVisited(visitedCities)) {

        currentCity = Random().nextInt(distances.size)

        if (!visitedCities[currentCity]) {
            orderToBeVisited.add(currentCity)
            visitedCities[currentCity] = true
        }
    }
    return orderToBeVisited
}
```

And the class for optimization:

```
import java.util.*

class GreedyHeuristic(distances: Array<IntArray>, initialSoltion: MutableList<Int>) {

    val mInitialSolution: MutableList<Int> = initialSoltion
    val mDistances: Array<IntArray> = distances

    fun optimize(): MutableList<Int> {
        var bestSolution = mInitialSolution
        var newSolution = mInitialSolution
        var bestDistance = findTotalDistance(mDistances, bestSolution)
        var i = 0

        while (i <= 5) {
            println("best distance at start of loop: $bestDistance")

            var cityIndex1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE
            var cityIndex2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE

            while (cityIndex1 == cityIndex2) {
                cityIndex1 = Random().nextInt(mInitialSolution.size)
                cityIndex2 = Random().nextInt(mInitialSolution.size)
            }

            val temp = newSolution.get(cityIndex1)
            newSolution.set(cityIndex1, newSolution.get(cityIndex2))
            newSolution.set(cityIndex2, temp)

            val newDistance: Int = findTotalDistance(mDistances, newSolution)
            println("new distance: $newDistance\n")

            if (newDistance < bestDistance) {
                println("New values gived to solution and distance")
                bestSolution = newSolution
                bestDistance = newDistance
            }
            i++
        }
        println("The distance of the best solution ${findTotalDistance(mDistances, bestSolution)}")
        return bestSolution
    }

    fun findTotalDistance(distances: Array<IntArray>, orderToBeVisited: MutableList<Int>): Int {

        var totalDistance = 0

        for (i in 0..orderToBeVisited.size - 2) {
            val fromCityIndex = orderToBeVisited.get(i)
            val toCityIndex = orderToBeVisited.get(i + 1)
            totalDistance += distances[fromCityIndex].get(toCityIndex)
        }
        return totalDistance
    }

}
```

Comment: it could be that you are passing the MutableList to some function that modifies it, i am currently setting up the project in idea

Comment: `bestSolution = newSolution.toMutableList()` this seems to fix it, this makes sure the list does not get modified later

Comment: Your suggestion helped alot, but still got a few unexpected results. Also changed `var bestSolution = mInitialSolution.toMutableList` and `var newSolution = mInitialSolution.toMutableList` and it runs fine every time now. Thanks alot for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin (and JVM languages in general) doesn't copy values unless you specifically ask it to. This means that, when you do this:

```
var bestSolution = mInitialSolution
var newSolution = mInitialSolution
```

You're not setting `bestSolution` and `newSolution` to separate copies of `mInitialSolution`, but rather making them point at same `MutableList`, so mutating one mutates the other. Which is to say: your problem isn't that `bestSolution` is getting overwritten, it's that you're accidentally modifying it every time you modify `newSolution`.

You then reuse `newSolution` for every iteration of your `while` loop without ever creating a new list. This leads us to two things:

- Because `newSolution` still aliases `bestSolution`, modifying the former also modifies the latter.
- `bestSolution = newSolution` doesn't do anything.

As mentioned in a comment, the easiest way to fix this is by making strategic use of `.toMutableList()`, which will force copying the list.You can achieve this by making this change at the top:

```
var bestSolution = mInitialSolution.toMutableList()
var newSolution = mInitialSolution.toMutableList()
```

Then inside the loop:

```
bestSolution = newSolution.toMutableList()
```

Incidentally: As a general rule, you should probably return and accept `List` rather than `MutableList` unless you specifically want it to be part of the contract of your function that you're going to mutate things in-place. In this particular case, It would've forced you to either do something icky (like unsafe-casting `mInitialSolution` to `MutableList`, which should sound all sorts of warning bells in your head), or copy the list (which would've nudged you towards the right answer)